# Persist redis data (aof and rdb files) in a directory location for redis 6.0.x version

Tags: redis, redis-cluster

**Goal** : Persist/write redis data in form of AOF/RDB files to different file system mount locations or directories and also being able to recreate the redis server from these files previously written in case redis server goes down.

**Redis version used** : 6.0.8

Given the above goal of being able to write the AOF/RDB files to persisting file system mount location directory /mount/redis-data/ , how can this be achieved for redis version 6.0.8.

One of the ways I was trying is by updating appendfilename parameter with file locations which obviously cannot be done as it doesn't allows that

I was following https://redis.io/docs/management/config-file/

So what other options Redis provides to achieve the above goal besides redis.conf file ? .